# Text is not coming properly with Custom LabelField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, custom-fields, labelfield

I am implementing Custom LabelField in my app. It is working fine with small fonts, when I increase the font size it will not show properly. Here you can see it in this image.

[image]

You can see in the image it is showing only the half of the text. How can I overcome this.

Here I am giving my code for custom LabelField. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public class CustomLabelField extends Field  
{  
    private String label;  
    private int fontSize;
    private int foregroundColor;  
    private int backgroundColor;  
    public CustomLabelField(String label, int fontSize, int foregroundColor,  
                     int backgroundColor,long style)  
    {  
        super(style);  
        this.label = label;  
        this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;  
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;  
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }  

   protected void layout(int width, int height) {  

       setExtent(width, getFont().getHeight());  


   }  

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {  

       graphics.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);  
       graphics.clear();  
       graphics.setFont(setMyFont());  
       graphics.setColor(foregroundColor);  
       graphics.drawText(label, 0, 0, (int)(getStyle()& DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | DrawStyle.HALIGN_MASK),getWidth() - 6);  
   }  

   // Get font for the label field  
   public Font setMyFont()  
   {  
     try {  
         FontFamily alphaSansFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");  
         Font appFont = alphaSansFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN, fontSize, Ui.UNITS_pt);  
         return appFont;  

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    return null;  
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `layout` method you are setting the height of your field to the current default font height. This means that when you draw using a larger font the text is cropped. To solve this change your layout method to:

```
protected void layout(int width, int height) {  

    int fieldHeight = Ui.convertSize(fontSize, Ui.UNITS_pt, Ui.UNITS_px);
    setExtent(width, fieldHeight);  
}
```

This converts your desired font size into pixels and uses that to set your field height.

Answer (score 3):

What about creating your `CustomLabelField` by just extending `LabelField`? Then the layout, the complexity of painting text (alignment, wrap, style consideration etc.) and other tasks will be done by the `LabelField` itself if you set the appropriate style bit in constructor.

And you can just apply any font on that `Field` by just invoking `setFont(Font)`. The field itself will adjust its size and drawing. Check following snippets.

---

CustomLabelField implementation:

```java
class CustomLabelField extends LabelField {
    private int foregroundColor;
    private int backgroundColor;

    public CustomLabelField(String label, int foregroundColor,
            int backgroundColor, long style) {
        super(label, style);
        this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.setColor(foregroundColor);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

---

Example:

```java
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public Font getMyFont(int fontSize) {
        try {
            FontFamily alphaSansFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");
            return alphaSansFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN, fontSize, Ui.UNITS_pt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public MyScreen() {
        CustomLabelField clf = new CustomLabelField(
                    "Main",
                    Color.WHITE,
                    Color.BLACK,
                    LabelField.ELLIPSIS);

        // Font setup
        clf.setFont(getMyFont(20));

        add(clf);
    }
}
```